# Run Time Error 91 in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this function to check blank and non-blank cell in VBA.

```
Function toCheckBlanks(rng1 As String, rng2 As Range)
Dim iBlank&, iNonBlank& '& declare variables as long
Set main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Nothing

Set rng = main.Range(rng1 & [rng2].Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious).Row)

With WorksheetFunction
    iNonBlank = .CountA(rng) 'count non-blank
    iBlank = .CountBlank(rng) ' count blank
End With

If iBlank > 0 Then
    toCheckBlanks = True
End If

Set rng = Nothing
End Function
```

I've tried to use it this way:

```
If toCheckBlanks("O23:O", Range("O23:O32")) Then exit sub
```

This line returns an error:

> Object variable or With block Variable not set

```
Set rng = main.Range(rng1 & [rng2].Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious).Row)
```

But sometimes if I run it, it does not have an error, and other times it errors.
Any heads up?

Comment: Why do you have `rng2` within evaluation brackets?  Why not just use `Set rng = main.Range(rng1 & rng2.Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious).Row)`?

Comment: @YowE3K I've also tried doing it. It still returns the same error. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have something in cells `O23:O32`?  If the `.Find` doesn't find anything, it will return a rage of `Nothing`.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for this, I forgot considering this :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Function toCheckBlanks(rng1 As String, rng2 As Range) As Boolean
    Dim iBlank&, iNonBlank& '& declare variables as long
    Dim FindResult As Range
    Set main = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rng As Range

    Set FindResult = rng2.Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious)
    If FindResult Is Nothing Then
        'do whatever is appropriate if rng2 is Empty
        '...
        toCheckBlanks = False
    Else
        Set rng = main.Range(rng1 & FindResult.Row)

        With WorksheetFunction
            iNonBlank = .CountA(rng) 'count non-blank
            iBlank = .CountBlank(rng) ' count blank
        End With

        toCheckBlanks = iBlank > 0

    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

your function syntax is not so good

firstly you should specify the return data type of the function i.e.

```
Function toCheckBlanks(rng1 As String, rng2 As Range) as Boolean
```

also you only set the value of toCheckBlanks (the value being returned by the function) in your if statement on the condition (iBlank > 0). therefore if iBlank is <= 0 your function will not work properly. You need to ensure toCheckBlanks is always set, usually this is done by initialising it to a default value at the start of the function

looks like there is a bunch of noise and unnecessary lines in your code, it needs a bit of a tidy up

Comment: Specifying the return data type of the function doesn't make any changes in the error. Thanks.

Comment: The other issue I listed is more important.. it potentially explains why it works sometimes and it fails sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I think you can shorten it down to:

```
Function toCheckBlanks(rng1 As String, rng2 As Range) As Boolean
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = rng2.Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range(rng1 & rng2.Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious).Row)
        toCheckBlanks = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng) > 0
    End If
End Function
```